# setTimeout doesn't work in this clock project

Tags: html

For some reason, the timeout doesn't work, and the clock numbers stay the same as they started initially. I tried `setInterval()` but it didn't work either.

Code below, or see it here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/doublepicebs/pen/oNbZEqZ)

```js
// Variables
var hourN = document.getElementById("hoursD");
var minuteN = document.getElementById("minutesD");
var secondN = document.getElementById("secondsD");
var hour, minute, second = 0;
var date = new Date();

// Functions
function refresh() {
  
  hour = date.getHours();
  minute = date.getMinutes();
  second = date.getSeconds();
  hour > 12 ? hour = hour - 12 : hour;
  
  hourN.innerText = hour;
  minuteN.innerText = minute;
  secondN.innerText = second;
  
  var t = setTimeout(function(){ refresh(); }, 1000);
  
}

refresh();
```

```html
<h1 align="center">
    <span id="hoursD"></span> : <span id="minutesD"></span> : <span id="secondsD"></span>
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

`date` still holds the initial value.
you should update it inside refresh.

```
// Variables
var hourN = document.getElementById("hoursD");
var minuteN = document.getElementById("minutesD");
var secondN = document.getElementById("secondsD");
var hour, minute, second = 0;
var date = new Date();

// Functions
function refresh() {
  
  date = new Date();
  hour = date.getHours();
  minute = date.getMinutes();
  second = date.getSeconds();
  hour > 12 ? hour = hour - 12 : hour;
  
  hourN.innerText = hour;
  minuteN.innerText = minute;
  secondN.innerText = second;
  
  var t = setTimeout(function(){ refresh(); }, 1000);
  
}

refresh();
```

By the way.. `setInterval` would be better for this function.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @Doublepicebs you're welcome :) happy coding!
If the answer, or another answer, solved your problem, you can accept it so others can find the solution if they will meet the same situation. :) See also How does accepting an answer work: meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/785217

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setTimeout` here. Also your css remove h1 from viewport. Also you have to update your `date` value inside of `refresh` function.

```
// Variables

var hourN = document.getElementById("hoursD");

var minuteN = document.getElementById("minutesD");

var secondN = document.getElementById("secondsD");

var hour, minute, second = 0;


// Functions

function refresh() {

  var date = new Date();

  hour = date.getHours();

  minute = date.getMinutes();

  second = date.getSeconds();

  hour > 12 ? hour = hour - 12 : hour;

  hourN.innerText = hour;

  minuteN.innerText = minute;

  secondN.innerText = second;


}
setInterval(function(){ refresh(); }, 1000);
```

```
* {

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

  box-sizing: border-box;

}

body {


  padding-bottom: calc(50% - 200px);

}

h1 > span {

  color: black;

}

h1 {

  color: #2979ff;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `date` variable inside of the `refresh()` function so that it gets the current date every second. Otherwise it's only going to return the date the user had when they first loaded the script.

Also, I would move the timer outside of the `refresh()` function and use `setInterval` to call it.

Here's the updated code:

```
var hourN = document.getElementById("hoursD");
var minuteN = document.getElementById("minutesD");
var secondN = document.getElementById("secondsD");
var hour, minute, second = 0;


// Functions
function refresh() {
  var date = new Date();
  hour = date.getHours();
  minute = date.getMinutes();
  second = date.getSeconds();
  hour > 12 ? hour = hour - 12 : hour;

  hourN.innerText = hour;
  minuteN.innerText = minute;
  secondN.innerText = second;
}

refresh();
setInterval(function(){ refresh(); }, 1000)
```